# What does it mean when a Collection insert results in a 404?

Tags: meteor

I have a very simple test app in meteor, and I've created a collection like so:

```
var people = new Meteor.Collection("people");
```

When I try to do a simple insert, like this:

```
people.insert({name: "Benson"});
```

I get a 404 error with the text "Method not found".  I admit there's a good chance I've fat-fingered something here, but I'd love to know both what's wrong, and why the error is so opaque (i.e. where it's coming from).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This error almost certainly means you've only defined `people` on the client, but not on the server.  The `new Meteor.Collection('people')` declaration has to also run on the server, or else the server doesn't know how to run your insert command.

Be sure you're calling `new Meteor.Collection` on both the client and the server.  Are you calling it inside `if (Meteor.is_client)`, or in a file under the `client` subdirectory?

Some more details: On the server, `new Meteor.Collection` defines three remote methods (`Meteor.methods`) that insert, update, and remove documents in the named MongoDB collection.  On the client, the same command creates an in-memory minimongo collection that lives inside the browser, and defines three *stubs* that simulate the methods by applying the same change to the minimongo collection.  By only declaring the collection on the client, your client code runs the local insert just fine, but when it asks the server to perform the real insert, the server has no idea what method you've asked it to execute.

Comment: Hmm, I agree that the error message isn't up to our usual standards.

Comment: `if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.startup(function () {
    console.log("Starting Up");
  });
  people = new Meteor.Collection("people");
}`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use Collection only on Client side and you don't need to save that data to server you can declare your collection in "client" folder or in .isClient() function by passing null to the constructor like this:

```
if(Meteor.isClient()){
// Some other code
...

onlyClientCollection = new Meteor.Collection(null);

// Some other code
...
}
```

Comment: Good answer re: the null, fixed my issue.